# How to avoid a flicking on the Pivot control of also firing its parent DragCompleted GestureListener

Tags: windows-phone-8, pivot, gesture

I have a Grid with a GestureListener that detects when the user flicks horizontally to show a hidden menu. But now I need to put a Pivot inside this Grid and when the user flicks horizontally the Pivot, I needed to avoid the GestureListener of also listening to that flick so that the Pivot moves to the previous or next PivotItem and the hidden menu stays hiden.

My Xaml is like this:

`<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            <toolkit:GestureListener DragCompleted="GestureListener_OnDragCompleted" />
        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <Grid>
             <controls:Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding myImages}">
                ....
             </controls:Pivot>
        </Grid>
     </Grid>`

Any suggestions on how to avoid a flicking on the Pivot control of also firing GestureListener_OnDragCompleted?

### Update

I found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.frameworkelement.useoptimizedmanipulationrouting%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) which seems to be something similar to my problem, but their solution still doesn't work for me. They suggested "Consider that you have a Panorama or **Pivot** control that includes a user control. Also, consider that the user control can handle horizontal gestures. If you want the user control to receive the horizontal gestures, you must set the **UseOptimizedManipulationRouting** property on the user control to **false**."

Comment: Don't do that. Flicking already means navigation inside the pivot. It might be confusing for users if you redefine what flick means

Comment: I don't have option, it's a requirement =/
We have this hidden menu which can be shown by tapping a button placed on the right top corner or by swiping to the right (just like the Facebook app works to show the menu hidden in the left side of the screen). So now in this specific page I also need to place a Pivot so the user can swipe on top of this Pivot to see the next/previous image or can also swipe outside the Pivot to show the menu.

Comment: Oh, just a note: cold be that I am confusing the terms "swipe" and "flicking".. I don't really know the difference between the two. Let me know if what I need to do is not understandable then I try to explain with other words :}